# c++ keep getting fpermissive error in function calls

Tags: c++

I keep getting an fpermissive error in my code where i call the functions im not sure why. the two errors are:
error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

132 |   playGame(winnerWord, wordArray);

error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
90 |   buildResult(guess, winWord);

Im pretty new to C++ so im not sure what to do, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
void playGame(char winWord, string arr[2315]) {

  string guessWord;

  cout << "Ok. I am thinking of a word with 5 letters." << endl;
  cout << "What word would you like to guess?" << endl;

  getline(cin, guessWord);

  while (verifyExists(guessWord, arr) == 2)
    {

      cout << "The word: " << guessWord << " is not in the word list" << endl;
      getline(cin, guessWord);

    }

  while (verifyExists(guessWord, arr) == 3)
    {

      cout << "You must enter a word that is 5 letters in length: " << endl;
      getline(cin, guessWord);

    }

  cout << guessWord << endl;

  char guess[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      guess[i] = guessWord[i];
    }

  buildResult(guess, winWord);

}

int main() {

  string wordArray[2315];

  ifstream myfile ("proj1_data.txt");

  cout << "          Welcome to UMBC Wordle" << endl;

  if (myfile.is_open())
    {

      string word;

      int loop = 0;

      while (getline(myfile, word))
        {
          wordArray[loop++] = word;
        }

      cout << " " << endl;
      cout << "          Your file was imported!" << endl;
      cout << "          2315 Words imported" << endl;
      cout << " " << endl;

      myfile.close();

    }

  srand(time(0));
  string chosenWord = wordArray[rand() % 2315];

  char winnerWord[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      winnerWord[i] = chosenWord[i];
    }

  playGame(winnerWord, wordArray);


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Reminder:  a `char` type is a single character.  A `char *` is a pointer *to a single character*.  The compiler is saying you are converting a pointer to a single character to a character.  Hint:  an array of characters can be converted to a pointer to character.

Comment: You can start commenting out statements until the error goes away and the last line commented is the suspect line.  Or you can comment out all lines, then uncomment and see which causes the issue.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews im not using any pointers though

Comment: Please indicate which statement is at line 132, as that is the line number that the compiler is referencing.

Comment: Instead of passing a huge array of strings, consider passing one vector of strings; by constant reference:  `void playGame(char winWord, const std::vector<std::string>& arr)`

Comment: In `main()`, the call  `playGame(winnerWord, wordArray)` passes an array of five `char` as the first argument.   The function is specified as accepting a single `char` as the first argument.    Option 1: pass a single `char`, such as `winnerWord[0]`.     Passing a single `char` will stop the compiler complaining.  You need to determine *which* `char` to pass.   Option 2:  change the function so it accepts an array (or pointer) [which will rely on logic in the function to decide what characters to act on].